# Locating a cell image

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have inserted an image in an Excel table successfully; but now I have a huge trouble, I want the images to be centered in a single cell, since when I export the file with the images, they seems to be inside one cell., but when I look closely the image is some millimeters our of the cell which makes difficult to work. The image doesn't recognize which cell it belong to. using the library of Apache POI.

I hope you can help me, thanks.

here I send you part of the code,

```
int posReporte = 1;
int posRow = 1;
for (List<Object> dr : datosReportes) {
   Row filaReporte = hojaReporte.createRow(posReporte);
   for (int a = 0; a < dr.size(); a++) {
      Cell celdaD = filaReporte.createCell(angel);*
      celdaD.setCellStyle(estiloDatos);
      Object obj = dr.get(angel);
      if (a == 0) {
         hojaReporte.setColumnWidth(a, 180 * 38);
         filaReporte.setHeight(Short.valueOf("1500"));
         //Add image data to the book
         try {
            if (directorio("S:\\", dr.get(1) + "_mini")) {
               InputStream is = new FileInputStream("S:\\" + dr.get(1) + "_mini.jpg");
               byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);

               int pictureIdx = wb.addPicture(bytes, Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG);
               is.close();
               CreationHelper helper = wb.getCreationHelper();
               Drawing drawing = hojaReporte.createDrawingPatriarch();
               //Add image
               ClientAnchor anchor = helper.createClientAnchor();
               anchor.setCol1(o);
               anchor.setRow1(posRow);
               anchor.setAnchorType(o);
               Picture pict = drawing.createPicture(anchor, pictureIdx);
               pict.resize();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            continue;
        }
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post some code that you are using?

Comment: Kindly provide some code for better understanding of your problem.

Comment: here I send you part of the code,